# golang Template json to yml format

Tags: go, yaml, go-templates

Hi I am looking to Create the Yml in the following format using the Json data passed to our go api.

```
zookeeper:
  configs:
  
    zookeeper_user: custom-user
    zookeeper_group: custom-group
      
    zookeeper_copy_files:
       - source_path: /path/to/file.txt
         destination_path: /tmp/file.txt

    zookeeper_Some_otherfile:
       - source_path: /path/to/file.txt
         destination_path: /tmp/file.txt
  hosts:
    ip-172-31-34-246.us-east-2.compute.internal:
      zookeeper_id: 2
    ip-172-31-37-15.us-east-2.compute.internal:
      zookeeper_id: 3
    ip-172-31-34-231.us-east-2.compute.internal:
      zookeeper_id: 1


      # zookeeper:
      #   properties:
      #     initLimit: 6
      #     syncLimit: 3
      # zookeeper_server:
      #   properties:
      #     num.io: 15
      # zookeeper_registry:
      #   properties:
      #     key: val
      # Zookeeper_center:
      #   properties:
      #     key: val
```

Using the following Struct to Unmarshal json data

```
type Service struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Hosts []Host `json:"hosts"`
    Configs  map[string]interface{} `json:"configs"` 

}

type Host struct {
    HostName         string                 `json:"host_name"`
    CustomHostConfig map[string]interface{} `json:"config"`
}
```

```
{{ range $s := $.Services }}
{{ $s.Name }}:
  {{ range $k,$v := $s.Vars }}{{ $k }}: "{{ $v }}"
  {{ end }}
  hosts:
    {{ range $h := $s.Hosts }}
    {{ $h.HostName }}: {{ range $k,$v := $h.CustomHostConfig }}
       {{ $k }}: "{{ $v }}"
      {{ end }}
{{ end }}{{ end }}
```

I am using the above template code which creates the following code fine

```
zookeeper:
  configs:

    zookeeper_user: custom-user
    zookeeper_group: custom-group


  hosts:
    ip-172-31-34-246.us-east-2.compute.internal:
      zookeeper_id: 2
    ip-172-31-37-15.us-east-2.compute.internal:
      zookeeper_id: 3
    ip-172-31-34-231.us-east-2.compute.internal:
      zookeeper_id: 1
```

I need help in adding the following config section to the final yml file in sort of the dynamic way based on the user input passed as part of the key value json using `Configs  map[string]interface{}` json:"configs"`. With the right level of indentation.

```
   zookeeper_copy_files:
       - source_path: /path/to/file.txt
         destination_path: /tmp/file.txt

    zookeeper_Some_otherfile:
       - source_path: /path/to/file.txt
         destination_path: /tmp/file.txt

      # zookeeper:
      #   properties:
      #     initLimit: 6
      #     syncLimit: 3
      # zookeeper_server:
      #   properties:
      #     num.io: 15
      # zookeeper_registry:
      #   properties:
      #     key: val
      # Zookeeper_center:
      #   properties:
      #     key: val
```

Comment: It is rather unclear what you want to ask and I think you are giving far more information than you need. Please provide a *minimal* example of what you want to do and what you tried so that it's clear what you're asking. In particular, you refer to templates a lot but don't show how you intend to use them. Your initial example shows some Go type but doesn't show what you're doing with it. Mind that you can just dump Go values as YAML without any templating.

Comment: I have updated the question , Hope its more clear now .

Comment: Due to the significance of white space,  yaml is even more difficult to template than json.   Instead,  model your data with Go data structures,  then use `yaml.Marshal` to write it out as yaml.   This is coming from somebody who has spent hundreds of hours maintaining templates that were supposed to be valid yaml or json

Comment: Besides using host names as a keys makes it difficult to consume resulting yaml. Consumer will need to implement custom serializer for `hosts`. Consider changing it to the list. Example: https://go.dev/play/p/1CEZrOhS_po .

Answer (score 0):

Don't write YAML with go templates, simply use a YAML implementation, e.g.:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Service struct {
    Name    string                 `json:"name"`
    Hosts   []Host                 `json:"hosts"`
    Configs map[string]interface{} `json:"configs"`
}

type Host struct {
    HostName         string                 `json:"host_name"`
    CustomHostConfig map[string]interface{} `json:"config"`
}

var services []Service

// create some sample data similar to what you show
func init() {
    var zk Service
    zk.Name = "zookeeper"
    zk.Configs = map[string]interface{}{
        "zookeeper_user":  "custom-user",
        "zookeeper_group": "custom-group",
    }
    zk.Hosts = []Host{
        {"ip-172-31-34-246.us-east-2.compute.internal",
            map[string]interface{}{
                "zookeeper_id": 2,
            }},
        {"ip-172-31-37-15.us-east-2.compute.internal",
            map[string]interface{}{
                "zookeeper_id": 3,
            }},
    }
    services = []Service{zk}
}

func main() {
    out := make(map[string]interface{})
    for _, service := range services {
        var hosts = make(map[string]interface{})
        for _, host := range service.Hosts {
            hosts[host.HostName] = host.CustomHostConfig
        }
        out[service.Name] = map[string]interface{}{
            "hosts":   hosts,
            "configs": service.Configs,
        }
    }
    bytes, err := yaml.Marshal(out)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

output ([go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RD8SyLId8Hv)):

```yaml
zookeeper:
    configs:
        zookeeper_group: custom-group
        zookeeper_user: custom-user
    hosts:
        ip-172-31-34-246.us-east-2.compute.internal:
            zookeeper_id: 2
        ip-172-31-37-15.us-east-2.compute.internal:
            zookeeper_id: 3
```

This immediately fixes any problem you have with deeply nested data, because YAML just dumps the structure as-is.

Comment: Thanks @flyx, how about if user wanted to add the additional configs I mentioned on the example . For example `  zookeeper_copy_files:` section  . They value of the section can be dynamic .

Comment: @user121080 configs is a `map[string]interface{}` and therefore can also take slices and maps as content, try it!

Comment: .May be missing the trick I have added the value and getting error. its the line 39 

https://go.dev/play/p/zNz0o41eDA7

Comment: @user121080 You need to give the whole YAML structure as go structure, not give parts of YAML special characters in strings, that won't work. [fixed version](https://go.dev/play/p/IqIrYeCKRwY). Reading JSON that is structured accordingly will do this.

Comment: Thanks very much @flyx , Much appreciated for clarification